# Draw in the 2D plane the graph of y=f(x) in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to find out how to do this.

All the examples which I find online, are asking me to first generate some list of points/couples (x,y) and then plot these couples.

But I don't quite want this... Is there a library/module where I can just:

1. provide the interval for x;
2. the formula/function for y (y=f(x));
3. ... maybe also specify which part of the plane to visualize

and just have the library draw the graphic of y.

I guess there should be a way to do this since it does not seem complicated at all. Seems a pretty standard things, I think.

**Example:

Say I want to plot `y = sqrt(x*(1-x))`  for `x` in `[0,1]`... but show this drawing in a 600x400 screen area (scaled properly). How do I do this?**

Comment: I didn't really mean a "recommend me a library"... OK... I meant... some example using any library! I mean... of course we're not going to draw the pixels one by one with low level code here.

Comment: Maybe there is a misconception? When you ask matplotlib to plot something, it will *need* a list of points. But generating such list as as easy as specifying an interval. So at that point the question is pretty unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is tagged with matplotlib, here is how it's done; for example plot y=f(x)=x^2 in the interval [-3,3].

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

interval = -3,3
f = lambda x: x**2

x = np.linspace(*interval, 301)
plt.plot(x, f(x))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know of this linspace function. Is there a way also to say... make my whole drawing in a 600x400 screen area e.g.? I mean, can we control the overall size of the rectangular area used to plot?

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(6,4), dpi=100))` ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you keep seeing suggestions to generate points is that in order to draw the curve on a computer screen, a set of points must be generated to determine which pixels to set. As a human we tend to think that the graph of a function is based on the function. For a computer to do it is needs to know at every point on the screen, is this point part of the function or not. A screen is just a bit array of pixels. For the computer to know which pixel to set, it must know whether it is on the curve or not. The easiest way to do that is to generate a set of pixels which are on the curve - that is, create points (x,y) that satisfy y=f(x).

Any library that draws the curve will generate the points. This step becomes so trivial that most graphing libraries will expect you've already done that step. There's not much point the library doing it, because the difference would only be equivalent to:

```
plt.plot(xvals, f(xvals))
```

compared to:

```
yvals = f(xvals)
plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
```

Comment: Well... OK but ... Say I want to plot y = sqrt(x*(1-x))  for x in [0,1]... but show this drawing in a 600x400 screen area (scaled properly). How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe this comment above is how I should have phrased my question in the very beginning.

Comment: I'm not sure where the confusion is. Assuming you want a resolution of 1 point per pixel, then just x=np.linspace(0,1,400); plt.plot(x, [math.sqrt(i*(1-i)) for i in x]). Maybe one of these is your question: how to work with arrays or how to specify resolution when plotting points?